# How to implement a blocking processing loop?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, loops, c++17

I'd like to implement a processing loop in a worker thread so that it processes data from a queue when there's something and blocks (the thread sleeps) otherwise...is this even possible? Should also work without any noticeable delays.

Something simple like this:

```
std::deque<Foo> queue;

void worker() 
{
    while (active) {
        blockAndWaitForData();

        while (!queue.empty()) {
            doSomething(queue.front());
            queue.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the queue would need to be locked plus some other details.

The Linux API could also be used directly if needed.

Comment: Look at [_condition variables_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), plus it may be better to use some form of _lock-free queue_ (such as `boost::lockfree::queue`).

Comment: Use a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to signal the availability of data.  Better still, make use of an [existing threadsafe queue implementation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/tbb-documentation/top/intel-threading-building-blocks-developer-reference/containers/concurrentqueue-template-class.html).

Comment: There's a name for what you are asking: You are asking for a _blocking queue_. That is, a queue whose methods automatically block a caller that tries to access the `front` object until there is an object there to be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something that will suit your needs in C++11 standard. It is `condition_variable`. It allows you to wait until it is notified by other thread. So your worker could wait until producer notifies it like this. Note this is very dumbed down example and in most situations insufficent but gives you gist how to do it

```
std::deque<int> q;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void worker() {
    while (active) {
        std::deque<int> vals;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            cv.wait(l, []{return q.empty();});
            vals = std::move(q);
            q.clear();
        }
        for (const auto& val : vals)
            doSomething(val);
    }
}

void producer() {
    while (active) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            q.push_back(produce());
        }  
        cv.notify_one();
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that with this code, `m` is locked during the execution of `doSomething`, which might be quite inefficient in practice. I am not sure if OP sees this, if they are not familiar with condition variables.